# SQL Server 2005 The Select permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error in SQL Server 2005

`The Select permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)`

I have zero idea how to fix this, I have googled around and cant find a clear answer (steps like this Go Here-> then here -> enter this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That seems like permissions problem, so firstly you have to think about what security level is necessary/needed for your user. This I leave up to you.

Secondly if you wish to grant permission for your user, you have to have another login with adequate privileges. If you don't have, you must ask someone (probably db administrator) who have then.

And now the clear answer is:

If you wish to grant to privileges to schema sys in your database, click database->security->schemas->sys->right click+properties->permissions-> browse for desired user-> grant desired permissions (in this case seems select should be enough).
Similarly you can grant perissions on various objects - tables, views, procedures. Or you can assign role with some predefined permission levels -> in databases->security->logins.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution **did solve** my issue. The `SELECT` permission was enough.